# My dropdown menu is contained within an #apdiv tag and is not visible over the scrolling content of my page

Tags: html, css

I have created an #apdiv tag with styling as follows:

```
#ApDiv
{
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
    float: left;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    z-index: +5;
}
```

I have 2 nav bars that are held within this fixed position #apdiv tag to get my page content to scroll under the div.  The scrolling part works fine, but my dropdown menu in the second nav bar is not visible over the top of the `<div id="apdiv"></div>`.

Is there a way that I can get the dropdown menu to extend out over the fixed div I have created?

Comment: 1. Need more css/html. 2. `z-index: +5;` ?

Comment: Need more details.if not try playing with position and z-index property of CSS.